# VSTS Pull request API - how to get the IdentityRef

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using VSTS Pullrequest create API method to automate the PR creation, in the request i need to provide various IdentityRef id values for createdby/autocompleteby/reviewers properties. In my case all i have is user details (like full name, email address - user1@domain.com ), in this case how do i retrieve the IdentityRef Guid so that i can pass it to PR Create API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the reply. 
I tried above "Users - Get" graph API but it needs the userDescriptor which i think it the GUID or some sort which isn't clear in the docs. 

I tried the user List graph api to list all users in the org but it only lists 500 users.

Comment: Hi @Mahende, did you success to override the `createdBy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Use [Graph - List Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0), but also check for a **X-MS-ContinuationToken** response header to determine if there is still additional paged data to be retrieved. If so, resend the request with the continuation token value until all values are returned:

- `GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=5.0-preview.1`, followed by
- `GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?continuationToken={continuationToken}&api-version=5.0-preview.1`

(I'm wondering if this is why you are only getting 500 users per your comment above. Unfortunately the documentation doesn't list the max page size for this API. If you *are* using the continuation token and all users are not being returned, that sounds like an API bug to me.)

2) Use [Get User Entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). This provides **top** and **skip** parameters. The **top** parameter has a 10000 record limit per the documentation.

- `GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?top=10000&api-version=5.0-preview.2`

Comment: Thank you Eric for the reply, I tried the Graph-List users with continuation token indeed it is solving my problem. I haven't used the continuation token parameter in my earlier runs.

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach is to use [Identities - Read Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read%20identities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) API, which allows us to query for the IdentityRef of a user [by email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read%20identities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#by-email), [by IdentityDescriptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read%20identities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#by-identitydescriptors), [by ids](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read%20identities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#by-ids), [by name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read%20identities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#by-name) and [by SubjectDescriptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read%20identities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#by-subject-descriptors). This avoids the costly approach of having to fetch the user graph repeatedly to locate a single user and also helps in directly getting the IdentityRef and not just the user descriptor.

Comment: love it, unfortunately this is apparently very new api and not available on even recent on-premise servers. Will remember it for when we join the cloud version ;) (then again I just saw the other solutions have the same problems... not sure how this is supposed to be done on TFS 2018/2019)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't this API return "Identity" not "IdentityRef"?  Is there a way to convert the Identity type to an IdentityRef?  You can't pass the Identity object to the IdentityRefWithVote constructor.